# Reuse QThread for different workers in python

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, qthread, worker

I want to use the same QThread for different workers. That is, first `worker1` is passed to the thread and runs. After it finishes, `worker2` should be passed to the thread and runs.

So, this is my attempt

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QAction
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QThread, pyqtSignal
from time import sleep

class MainWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
   def __init__(self):
      QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
      self.thread = QThread()
      self.worker1 = Worker1()
      self.worker1.finished.connect(self.w1_finish)
      self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.run)
      self.thread.start()
   
   def w1_finish():
       self.thread.quit()
       self.worker1.deleteLater()
       self.worker2 = Worker2()
       self.worker2.finished.connect(self.w2_finish)
       self.thread.started.connect(self.worker2.run)
       self.thread.start()
   
   def w2_finish():
       print("all done")


class Worker1(QObject):
   finished = pyqtSignal()
   def run():
      for i in range(5):
          print(f"This is worker1: {i}")
          sleep(1)
      self.finished.emit()

class Worker2(QObject):
   finished = pyqtSignal()
   def run():
      for i in range(5):
          print(f"This is worker2: {i}")
          sleep(1)
      self.finished.emit()
```

Strangely, this sometimes works as intended. I mean, I first get the outputs from worker 1 and then from worker2. However, in some cases, worker 2 seems to be executed after worker 1 has finished. Is there a problem? Should I use two separate thread instances for the task?

Comment: The actual solution is to use `QThreadPool` so you stop worrying about any particular thread. Just set up your workers and ask the threadpool to take care of them. You can read more [in this tutorial](https://www.pythonguis.com/tutorials/multithreading-pyqt-applications-qthreadpool/).

Comment: nice bro, that should do the work. Am I correct that Threadpool automatically deletes a thread if an worker ends?

Comment: You're correct - from the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtCore/QThreadPool.html): "`QThreadPool` deletes the `QRunnable` automatically by default".

Comment: Note that QRunnable doesn't inherit from QObject, so you won't be able to use its features (notably, signals) if not through a QObject "proxy" subclass. QThreadPool deletes the *runnable* by default, but you can change that. In any case, your question is a bit confusing, first you say "I first get the outputs from worker 1 and then from worker2", then "worker 2 seems to be executed after worker 1 has finished", which seems the same thing to me, maybe you switched one of those? Also, consider that, except from some very specific scenarios, you can just subclass QThread and override `run()`.

Answer (score 0):

I have coded something like this relying on QThreadPool():

```
import logging
import random
import sys
import time
from functools import partial

import qdarkstyle
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal, QRunnable, QThreadPool
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QApplication

logger = logging.getLogger()
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(threadName)s - %(message)s'))
logger.addHandler(handler)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


class Signals(QObject):
    started = pyqtSignal(int)
    finished = pyqtSignal()


class WorkerTask(QRunnable):

def __init__(self, function: str):
    super().__init__()
    self.function = function
    self.signals = Signals()

def run(self):
    time_to_reach_pos = random.randint(2, 5)

    for i in range(time_to_reach_pos):
        logger.debug(f"{self.function}: {i + 1}/{time_to_reach_pos}")
        time.sleep(0.3)

    self.signals.finished.emit()


class MainWin(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.run_long_task()

    @staticmethod
    def run_long_task():
        threadpool = QThreadPool()

        grid_pos_task = WorkerTask(function="Go to grid position")
        autofocus_task = WorkerTask(function="Autofocus")

        # grid_pos_task.signals.finished.connect(threadpool.deleteLater)
        grid_pos_task.signals.finished.connect(partial(threadpool.start, autofocus_task))
        # grid_pos_task.finished.connect(lambda : print("ok"))

        threadpool.start(grid_pos_task)

        threadpool.waitForDone()
        print("All tasks finished")
```